# What is wrong with my Clojure implementation of permutations

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, clojure-core.logic

I know that there are multiple ways to solve permutations using Clojure. 
I have tried creating a DCG (definite clause grammar) using Core.Logic but 
the DCG part of the library is too experimental and didn't work.

In the code below I try two different approaches. One is a list comprehension (commented out), which is similar to the way I would solve this problem in Haskell.

The second approach uses MapCat to apply cons/first to each return value from the 
recursive call to permutation. Remove item makes sure that I don't use the same letter more than once for each position.

Can someone please explain what is wrong with the list comprehension approach and what is wrong with the MapCat approach. It is much easier to reason about this kind of problem in Haskell - is there some perspective I am missing about Clojure?

```
(defn remove-item [xs]
   (remove #{(first xs)} xs )
)

(defn permutation [xs]

  (if (= (count xs) 1)
      xs

     ;(for [x xs y (permutation (remove-item xs))
     ;          :let [z (map concat y)]]
     ;          z)                    

     (mapcat #(map cons first (permutation (remove-item %)) ) xs)

  )
)
```

**Edit: @thumbnail solved the MapCat sub-problem in the comments already**

Comment: DCG is a TLA right? and what does recPermute do?

Comment: Sorry - I retyped the code into stackoverflow for readability and didn't copy everything faithfully - should be 'permutation'

Comment: @amalloy - my question wasn't about how to solve permutations in Clojure. Aside from the stackoverflow response, there are a multitude of sample permutation code online. My question is about why the implementation I tried didn't work - what deeper concept was I missing. So many people put half baked questions on here - this is a genuine attempt to understand how clojure works and a genuine question.

Comment: @stevemacn you can always ask the question again with a more specific title, such as "what's wrong with my Clojure implementation of permutations?"

Comment: Thank you Diego - I changed the question title to reflect your comment.

Comment: I think what you're after is something like this: 
`(defn perms [s]
  (case (count s)
    1 (list (seq s))
    (mapcat (fn [x] (map (partial cons x) (perms (disj s x)))) s)))
`, where `s` is expected to be a *set*. It has the same enumerative structure as your code. If I'm right, your errors of detail are evident. Take it out and try it. It works.

Comment: So everything makes sense (looks like mine even) except the anonymous function - what exactly are we doing mapping (partial cons x)? So cons becomes curried with x as an input and each item of the resulting sequence coming from the call to permutation? And disj is just replacing the need to remove the item?

Comment: @stevemacn `(partial cons x)` is equivalent to `#(cons x %)` or `(fn [coll] (cons x coll))`. It `cons`es `x` onto its sequential argument, which `map` runs through the `perm`s of everything else in `s`. The enclosing `mapcat` concatenates the result of applying this process to every element of `s`, considered as a sequence. So the function takes a *set* argument but returns a sequence of *sequences*. You should know - you essentially wrote it :).

Comment: @stevemacn So you're right about what `(partial cons x)` does; and `(disj s x)` *returns* set `s` without element `x`. By the way, I get the impression from your code that Haskell can destructure a non-empty set into arbitrary member `x` and remaining *set* `xs`. Try this in Clojure, and `xs` will be a *sequence*, not a set. You can look up standard functions such as `partial` or `conj` at [ClojureDocs](http://clojuredocs.org/) or [Grimoire](http://grimoire.arrdem.com/). Finally, if you want to carry this on, follow @amalloy's implicit advice and re-open a revised question elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much @thumbnail! This is amazingly helpful! It is nice to know that I wasn't too far off.

Comment: @stevemacn If you edit the question to be more clearly about "I know solution X works but I can't seem to solve it my own way. Here are some approaches I tried, and why I think they should have worked, but instead Y happens. What have I done wrong?" then I would happily reopen this. Or you could, of course, ask a new question to that general effect. As written, I still think this question is a duplicate of "how do I do permutations in Clojure".

Comment: @slimbo If this has been answered via comments, it would be good to write a real _answer_.

Answer (score 5):

We can simplify the `permutation` function to

```
(defn permutation [xs]
  (if (= (count xs) 1)
    xs
    (for [x xs
          y (permutation (remove-item xs))]
      (map concat y))))
```

Attempting to use it on anything plural produces `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: ...` whatever you are trying to permute.

There are two errors:

- `permutation` should return *a sequence* of sequences, even when there is
  only one of them; so `xs` should be `(list xs)`. This is what causes the exception.
- The permutation for a given `x` from `xs` and, given that, a permutation `y` of `xs` without `x`is just `(cons x y)`.

With these corrected, we have

```
(defn permutation [xs]
  (if (= (count xs) 1)
    (list xs)
    (for [x xs
          y (permutation (remove-item x xs))]
     (cons x y))))
```

For example,

```
(permutation (range 3))
;((0 1 2) (0 2 1) (1 0 2) (1 2 0) (2 0 1) (2 1 0))
```

---

The above works only if all the permuted things are different. At the other extreme ...

```
(permutation [1 1 1])
;()
```

Also,

- `count` scans the whole of a sequence. To find out if there is only
  one element, `(seq (rest xs))` is faster than `(= (count xs) 1)`.
- And the `remove` in `remove-item` scans the whole sequence. There is
  little we can do to mend this.

---

If we know that we are dealing with distinct things, it is simpler and faster to deal with them as a set:

```
(defn perm-set [xs]
  (case (count xs)
    0 '()
    1 (list (seq xs))
    (for [x xs, y (perm-set (disj xs x))]
      (cons x y)))
```

- It works for empty sets too.
- `count` is instant and `disj` is almost constant time, so this is
  faster.

Thus:

```
(perm-set (set '()))
;()

(perm-set (set (range 3)))
;((0 1 2) (0 2 1) (1 0 2) (1 2 0) (2 0 1) (2 1 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add support for duplicates by working with the index of the items in the original sequence. The function append-index returns a new sequence where the index and value are now in a vector. For example '(\a \b \c) -> '([0 \a] [1 \b] [2 \c] [3 \a]).

You then work with this sequence within the for loop, taking the index of the item when we want to remove it from the original and taking the value when we cons it to the tail sequence.

```
(defn remove-nth [coll n]
  (into (drop (inc n) coll) (reverse (take n coll))))

(defn append-index [coll]
  (map-indexed #(conj [%1] %2) coll))

(defn permutation [xs]
  (let [i-xs (append-index xs)]
  (if (= (count xs) 1)
    (list xs)
    (for [x i-xs
          y (permutation (remove-nth xs (first x)))]
      (cons (last x) y)))))
```

Thanks to the previous post, I was struggling with the permutation problem myself and had not considered using a for comprehension.